# Extracting each digit of an integer into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, int

My goal is to convert an integer:

```
int = 1234;
```

to an array:

```
int converted[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Can you give me a tip what I will need for programming this?

Comment: @Roux it is close, but reversed. Should give OP some ideas.

Comment: Roughly spoken: convert it into a string with `itoa` or `sprintf`, then scan the string.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your number is unsigned, you could try the following:

```
unsigned int i = 1234 ;
char array[5] ;

for(int j=0 ; i>0 ; j++, i/=10)
   array[5-j] = (char)(i%10) ;
```

If your integer is signed, you would need an extra element in the array and some minor modifications to the code to account for the sign.

If what you want is in fact an array containing the ASCII representations of the digits (e.g. 1234 -> {'1','2','3','4'}), you should replace the last line above with

```
   array[5-j] = (char)(i%10)+'0' ;
```